# Хеширование пароля

Tags: php

Какую функцию лучше использовать: hash или password_hash()?

Comment: password_hash().

Comment: Почему password_hash()?

Comment: Потому что эту функцию специально ввели для хеширования паролей.

Answer (score 2):

Вы должны использовать любую из двух.

- `crypt`
- `password_hash` внутри она использует `crypt`

Они обеспечивают надежное хеширование и учитывают различные уязвимости.

Для проверки хешей полученных с использованием `crypt` нужно использовать `hash_equals`, она обеспечивает защиту от атак по времени.

Для проверки хешей полученных с использованием `password_hash` нужно использовать `password_verify`.

Предпочтительно использовать `password_hash`/`password_verify`.

Comment: Для password_hash() нет ни какой hash_equals(), есть только password_verify()!

Comment: Это для сравнения хешей, а не для проверки пароля.

Comment: Вот я вам и говорю: попробуйте сравнить хеш от  password_hash() с использованием hash_equals() при логине :)

Comment: @Visman я говорил, что её надо использовать с hash_password? Нет. А вот с crypt её надо использовать. Я добавлю это в ответ.